# Summing by keyword

Tags: excel

I've got a spreadsheet with data in the following format

```
CountryCode   Amount    Date
US            100       01/01/13
UK            200       01/01/13 
US            150       02/01/13
UK            250       02/01/13
.
.
```

My aim is to sum up each country and output the totals for each country, is there a way to do it without calculating it for each country separately?

Comment: This is great, thanks. post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Santosh, you can use a PivotTable:

Select all cells which contain the data (including the header row). Click `Insert`, `Pivot Table`, then click <kbd>Ok</kbd>.

Drag `CountryCode` variable to the pivot table *Row Labels* field and drag the `Amount` variable to the *Values* field.
Make sure `Amount` is set to summation mathematical operation (it will some all amount values for each country). If one wants to change this operation just give a left click on `Sum of Amount` and click on *Value Field Settings* option. Then, choose the desired operation (count, average, max, etc).

You can also opt to put the `Date` variable in the *Report Filter* field, if you want to filter the amount for each country in a specific date of interest.

The picture below illustrates how the pivot table should look like, to accomplish the goal.
<sub>I used Excel 2007</sub>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the Subtotal feature.

1. Click the Data tab in Excel's ribbon toolbar
2. Click the Sort button and sort by your category column
3. Click the Subtotal button and fill in the dialog as appropriate, then click OK